# How to create custom API for custom shipping methods

Tags: shipping, api, soap

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site. we are doing Android App for the site....

we are using custom Shipping method in our site.

But in Android app, we are calling this API to get shipping methods : shoppingCartShippingList()

we are getting shipping method , but we are getting shipping charges as zero.

So we are planning to create a Custom API for this.

please help me how to create custom API for shipping method.

or please give me some good links so i can write custom API in easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit the page https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html for guidelines and instruction to create your own Magento API. Once you get used to with Magento API model you can extend it and add missing parts on the Magento API.

For e.g. https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport is an opensource Magento API that does the same. You can borrow some of the concepts from there. Hope this helps you.